Can GDAL produce multi-colored tile from ENC (S-57) data?
I have a collection of ENC files for the coast of Maine and would like to visualize them at various zoom levels using GDAL.
I know GDAL supports S-57 data, and, using OSGeo4W Shell commands, can successfully poll the individual *.000 ENC files using ogrinfo <file.000> for all layers, or ogrinfo <file.000> <layername> for details on a particular layer.
So far, I have been able to load each ENC into OSGeo4W, and successfully determine the latitude/longitude extents of the features contained in the file, and successfully extract the polygon or point coordinates that define each feature's outline or position.
I can see, via ogrinfo that a given feature in a layer (e.g., the BOYSAW layer) has an associated color and color pattern (e.g., COLOUR = (2:3,1) COLPAT = (1:2)), but GDAL does not seem to use this information when rasterizing from the ENC vector.
I understand that the colorization is based on the S-52 standard for ECDIS, and that there is a standard set of symbology as well as colors and patterns.
Is it possible, using GDAL without additional software appliances, to produce an S-52 compliant colorized raster from a specified S-57 (ENC) file? And if so, what examples might there be to help guide my effort?
Note: I know that there are applications that can display ENC files with all the required symbology, etc., for example NOAA's Office of Coast Survey (https://nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/enconline/enconline.html), and commerical tools like ArcGIS, but I am trying to put something together myself to work on any ENC file of interest, and natively with GDAL.
Related Question: This question asks something similar (Styling ENC data for Web?), but was posed over twelve years ago. I'm hoping something better has come along other than the accepted answer (which was to use Excel sheets and Python scripts).

GDAL has some rendering features in gdal_rasterize https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdal_rasterize.html and through OGR Styles https://gdal.org/en/latest/user/ogr_feature_style.html. However, I think that it would be better to use for example QGIS for rendering. See this article to start with https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/displaying-s57-nautical-charts-in-qgis-3-x/

I think the short answer is, no, this cannot be done natively in GDAL. :) The QGIS link you shared is an interesting read, however, so thank you!

This may be interesting as well https://github.com/LarsSchy/SMAC-M.
